# copy files between a specified date range

Tags: vbscript

I want to copy files from one folder to another which falls between a specific date range using VBS.

for example i want to copy files from 06/11/2009 to 06/12/2010. 
How can I do that  in VB script.

Comment: Hey jean, I am really grateful to those who helped me out so far but I dont know how to accept the answers. Could you please tell me????

Comment: ok guys thanks a lot. Yes, I have done it before but didn't knew its purpose. once again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is WMI an option? If so, here's a sample script based on the one from the *Hey, Scripting Guy!* article [How Can I Delete All Files Older Than a Specified Date?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/04/how-can-i-delete-all-files-older-than-a-specified-date.aspx):

```
strComputer = "." 

strFolder = "C:\FromFolder"
strNewFolder = "C:\ToFolder"

strDateFrom = "20090611000000.000000+00" ' 06/11/2009
strDateTo   = "20100612000000.000000+00" ' 06/12/2010


Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")

Set colFiles = oWMI.ExecQuery _ 
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='" & strFolder & "'} WHERE " _ 
        & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")

For Each oFile in colFiles
    If oFile.CreationDate > strDateFrom And oFile.CreationDate < strDateTo Then
        'WScript.Echo "Full path:     " & oFile.Name
        'WScript.Echo "Creation date: " & oFile.CreationDate

        oFile.Copy strNewFolder & "\" & oFile.FileName & "." & oFile.Extension
        oFile.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Here's a slightly different variant where date checks are included in the WMI query:

```
strComputer = "."
strDateFrom = "20090611000000.000000+00" ' 06/11/2009
strDateTo   = "20100612000000.000000+00" ' 06/12/2010
strNewFolder = "C:\ToFolder"
iFlags = 48

Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")

Set colFiles = oWMI.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile" & _
    " WHERE Drive = 'C:' AND Path = '\\FromFolder\\'" & _
    " AND CreationDate >= '" & strDateFrom & "'" & _
    " AND CreationDate <= '" & strDateTo & "'" _
    ,,iFlags)

For Each oFile in colFiles
    'WScript.Echo "Full path:     " & oFile.Name
    'WScript.Echo "Creation date: " & oFile.CreationDate

    oFile.Copy strNewFolder & "\" & oFile.FileName & "." & oFile.Extension
    oFile.Delete
Next
```

A few notes:

- The script is non-recursive, that is, it only moves files from the source folder itself and not its subfolders.
- Dates are specified in the UTC format. More info about this format is in the article I linked to.
- WMI doesn't include methods for moving files and folders, so the script copies then deletes the files.

Comment: @Jean-François: Yes, it's the WMI DATETIME format. It can be converted from and to VT_DATE using the [`SWbemDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393687.aspx) object as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.07.scriptingguy.aspx), but I was too lazy to add this to the script - let it be up to the OP.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't know this WMI way of doing things. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FileSystemObject`. The following will get the date a file was created:

```
   Dim fso, myfile, d
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   Set myfile = fso.GetFile("something.dat")
   d = myfile.DateCreated
   MsgBox d
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is an example of how to loop through the files in a given folder. For each file, you can check the date, decide whether you like it, and if so [copy the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).